# with which programming language social networks like facebook , or forums can be written?

Tags: theory, forum, social-networking

I wanna make a social network with some new ideas . I wonder with which programming languages , social networks , or forums can be written?
thanks .

Comment: With every language that allows server side web programming

Comment: Javascript, PHP, Java, ASP and many more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a wide variety of languages that could be used. Some of the more popular ones include PHP and ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into [elgg](http://elgg.org/).  It's a popular open source engine that powers social networks.  I believe it leverages LAMP, which is Linux, Apache, MySql, and PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Anything which can be written in one Turing-complete language can also be written in every other Turing-complete language. Since the vast majority of what we think of as "programming languages" are Turing-complete, this means that they can be written in pretty much any programming language.